# How to remove the last character along with newline character from every line in python?

Tags: python-2.7

In my program I am getting an o/p which is a string content like below:

TD_MAP1:
 TD_MAP2:
 TD_MAP5:
 TD_MAP4:

Now I want to convert it to a list containing only useful info like:
['TD_MAP1','TD_MAP2','TD_MAP3','TD_MAP4']

Can we make it through strip()?

Answer (score 0):

You can use split. It converts your string in a list seperate by a delimiter.

example :

```
a = "D_MAP1: TD_MAP2: TD_MAP5: TD_MAP4:"
b = a.split(":")
# b will be equal to ['TD_MAP1', ' TD_MAP2', ' TD_MAP5', ' TD_MAP4', '']
# you can remove the last sentence with b.pop(-1)
```

Comment: Now the list has become like:
['TD_MAP1', '\nTD_MAP2', '\nTD_MAP5', '\nTD_MAP4']

Comment: change split(":") by split(":/n")